# The parameter (a Grid) in my call of a static method gives an object reference required error

Tags: c#, .net

**There's a better explanation in edit!**

I'm learning my way through C# (I'm a student) and I'm making a game on my own. It's MasterMind. I've done all the code, but there is just 1 error that is responsible for not being possible to test my code.

So the function where the call is used is static, aswell as the method itself.
I'll give a code example because I don't know so good how to formulate the problem.

```
public static void ProcesColors(Models.Rij_Master HuidigConfig, int lengte)
{
    /* first get the control, so we can add changes to it */
    ucRij try = (ucRij) FindChildInGrid(Res, 0, 0);

    switch (lengte)
    {
        ...;
    }
}
```

He gives an error with Res, Res is a grid in a grid on my xaml page.
I've tried the ref keyword, (on the method parameter and in the definition of the parameters in the method), out, static, but none of these work.
The error is:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property)

So I know it needs a reference because it is a reference type, but I just don't know how to force it.

(Btw, my grid Res is inside a custom made control)

The method where I find my child in my grid is:

```
private static FrameworkElement FindChildInGrid(Grid g, int row, int col)
{
    var childs = g.Children.Cast<FrameworkElement>();
    return childs.Where(x => Grid.GetRow(x) == row && Grid.GetColumn(x) == col).FirstOrDefault();

}
```

I've done some research and there was a lot to find about static methods, variabels, ect... but nono on how to actually call them.

I hope my question is clear, and that's just not something stupid.
Sorry for the long post and already thank you for just reading it,

Greetings!

(deleted some things)

**EDIT::**

**It's better to first read in the bottom where I shall ask 1 defining question, if that one is answered then I won't need all the rest**

So... Where to begin with..
I have a class, MasterMind, and a class MasterMind_Row. I've also built some custom controls (that are all nested in one another).

The main idea is, if a user dubbel taps on a color element in the legend (ucLegend control), than it has to change the first available color in the tryout row. So I have 2 things to deal with, in my class MasterMind I have to change the CurrentConfig MasterMind_Row to its values so the class can check for correct colors, and I have to change the colors themselves in the custom control.

The code that you saw for ProcesColors is in my control ucGame.
There it selects the Row control that is on the correct place in the grid, and change it's background from the 4 borders.
I've achieved this by making 4 public properties in the RowClass where in the setter it changes the background of the borders.

This was all a bit of guide throughout my code, so that you would understand what I am trying to achieve.

Now I will give you the code path how it is achieved:
(In ucLegend, where the double click thing is achieved):

```
private void ProcesColor(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Border brd = (Border) sender;

            Brush selectColor = brd.Background;

            MasterMind.FillColorsByClick(selectColor);
        }
```

Then we go to the MasterMind class, where the click is processed.
Is this necesearry to be static? or can that be left out (it would solve everything)

```
public **static** void FillColorsByClick(Brush selectColor)
        {
            if (arrSelectionChoice.Length < 4)
            {
                /* resize array */
                ExpandArray1Pos(arrSelectionChoice);

                /* fill in the array */
                arrSelectonChoice[arrSelectonChoice.Length - 1] = selectColor;

                /* fill the color in on the right property (color1,color2,color3,color4) 
                in the MasterMind_Row CurrentConfig */
                FillElementsInRowObject();

                /* send the currentconfig Row (with it's colors) to the ucLegend control*/
                ucSpel.ProcesColors(HuidigConfig, arrSelectieKeuze.Length);
            }
        }
```

And now comes the code that I've posted before.
In the control **ucGame** we have the following:

```
public **static** void ProcesColors(Models.Rij_Master HuidigConfig, int lengte)
        {
            /* first select rowcontrol to make changes to it */
            ucRij tryout = (ucRij) FindChildInGrid(ref Res, 0, 0);

            switch (lengte)
            {
                case 1:
                tryout.Color1SetBackground = HuidigConfig.Color1;
            case 2:
                tryout.Color1SetBackground = HuidigConfig.Color1;
                tryout.Color2SetBackground = HuidigConfig.Color2;
            case 3:
                tryout.Color1SetBackground = HuidigConfig.Color1;
                tryout.Color2SetBackground = HuidigConfig.Color2;
                tryout.Color3SetBackground = HuidigConfig.Color3;
            case 4:
                tryout.Color1SetBackground = HuidigConfig.Color1;
                tryout.Color2SetBackground = HuidigConfig.Color2;
                tryout.Color3SetBackground = HuidigConfig.Color3;
                tryout.Color4SetBackground = HuidigConfig.Color4;
            }
        }
```

***What the main question is now, while taking a look again too my code is, is it neceseary that they all have the static property? I know once you made 1 static, you have to make the whole chain as static, but is it possible to do this without a static?***

The grid that I am taking out to select the element, is also in my ucGame control. So I can't pass it from the class or anywhere else.

---

I know this is a really long post, and I am really thankfull for the people who are reading this. I'm still a learning programmer but I wan't to become better, professional, therefore this project that I've made up for myself.

I have found already so many answers on stackoverflow, and am starting to become an active member myself too. I really like this site.

Sorry again for the long post, I hope this is not a stupid question..

My sincerely

Comment: Really sorry for the very long post, but after it's solved I'll break it down and edit it again so for the future it is more clear what the problem is and what the solution is... :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `ProcesColors` is a function you've added to your window's code-behind.

The problem, as you've alluded to, is that your `ProcesColors` function is `static` whereas `Res` is an instance of a `Grid` that's on your page. Therefore, `ProcesColors` doesn't know what `Res` is.  If `ProcesColors` is really supposed to stay `static`, then you would need to pass `Res` into it from whatever code calls `ProcesColors`. Alternatively, perhaps `ProcesColors` is not really supposed to be `static`. If you post the code for the function that calls `ProcesColors`, we might be able to help you out further.

Comment: But thank you for your time reading this :)
And can I manage to let the static method ProcesColors know what the Grid Res is? Or isn't this possible in c#?

And I can't pass Res from the code it is called from, because Res is declared in the control where I am writing the ProcesColors..